# How to center an object within an object relative to the position of the second object?

Tags: math, lua, numbers

I need to center an object that is inside another object on a screen and for this to be relative to the position of the second object

For example:

```
-------- screen --------
|                      |
|    --------          |
|    | text |          |
|    --------          |
------------------------
```

Code example to center text on a screen in `Lua`:

```lua
local x = math.floor(screenWidth / 2 - width / 2)

local y = math.floor(screenHeight / 2 - height / 2)
```

Comment: supposing the coordinates system has the 0,0 on the top right and works with top-right corder and width-height... is just `[parent.x+text.x, parent.y+text.y]` no?

Comment: No, because the 'text' object is inside another object and what I need is to calculate the position of 'text' inside the object with respect to the object's position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just center the object relative to your parent, then move it to its absolute position on the screen:

```lua
local x = parentX + math.floor((parentWidth - width) / 2)
local y = parentY + math.floor((parentHeight - height) / 2)
```

since Lua 5.3, you may use floor division (`//`) to shorten this:

```lua
local x = parentX + (parentWidth - width) // 2
local y = parentY + (parentHeight - height) // 2
```